# Is my answer to this power series representation problem right?

Tags: power-series

Find power series representation of the function
$f(x) = \frac{3}{x+2}$

\begin{align*}f(x) = \left(\frac{3}{x}\right)\frac{1}{1-\left(-\frac{2}{x}\right)}
     = \left(\frac{3}{x}\right) \sum{\left(-\frac{2}{x}\right)}^{n}\end{align*}

Comment: It is right! Just a hint, learn a few about latex

Comment: They probably mean a power series in $x$. Similar strategy, $\frac{3}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{1+x/2}$.

Comment: In the definition of power series that I know, negative exponents of $x$ are not allowed. So, technically, your answer $f(x)=\frac{3}{x} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{-2}{x}\right)^n$ would not be OK. @André Nicolas has a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

The usual meaning of power series is an expression of the form
$$c_0+c_1(x-a)+c_2(x-a)^2+c_3(x-a)^3+\cdots.$$
Your answer is not of that form.

In your problem, $a$ has unfortunately not been specified. The default assumption is that $a=0$.

Express your function as
$$\frac{3}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{1+x/2},$$
and use the same strategy as in the OP. You are probably expected to specify where your series converges.

Answer (score 0):

What you obtained $$\frac 3 x \sum_{n=0}^\infty{\left(-\frac{2}{x}\right)}^{n}$$ is the perfect series representation of $f(x) = \frac{3}{x+2}$ for **infinitely** large values of $x$.

For illustration, let us just consider the case of $x=10$ : the exact value is $\frac 14$ while the partial sum using five terms would be $\frac{1563}{6250}\approx 0.25008 $